# Can I Choose Optional Parameter based on Condition on Method Call?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, clr

If I have a method with the following signature:

```
void MyDummyMethod(<n_params>, Guid? foo = null, Guid? bar = null);
```

is it possible that, after I have specified all the `n params` I could, based on a condition, pass a value to either `foo` **or** `bar`?

For example:

```
void CallingDummyMethod()
{
    myType var = new myType { Prop = 1 };
    MyDummyMethod(<n_params_values>, if (var.Prop == 1) { foo: Guid.Empty } else { bar: Guid.Empty };
}
```

Now, I'm fully aware the code above isn't valid, and somewhat weird, I'm also aware that the method could be refactored to take the parameters in a different manner, but the question is if it's possible to write code that does that, call a specific parameter within a method call based on a condition?

Comment: Why? They were declared as conditional in the signature, I know I can specify only one by using the named parameter, the question is a bout being able to select one based on a condition.

Comment: I feel like you could use something like [partial function application](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application.aspx) to do this. `Action<Guid?> fooFunction = arg => MyDummyMethod(n_params, foo: arg); Action<Guid?> barFunction = arg => MyDummyMethod(n_params, bar: arg); (var.Prop == 1 ? fooFunction : barFunction)(Guid.Empty);` But this seems far worse than simply doing an `if/else` check. Maybe with a bit more thought/abstraction it would work better?

Comment: I do like that approach, however, it has the same disadvantage as I face now... the amount of duplicate code you have is directly proportional to `n`.

Comment: You _could_ write: `MyDummyMethod(<n_params_values>, foo: (var.Prop == 1) ? (Guid?)Guid.Empty : null, bar: (var.Prop != 1) ? (Guid?)Guid.Empty : null)`... you know... if you then want to duplicate the `null` default value in the method signature... and... the `var.Prop == 1` check... and make something really ugly... :(

Comment: @PedroC88 I don't have the context of your application, but, often, when this type of scenario comes up, it is able to be solved using polymorphism. Based on your example, it appears that polymorphism *might* be a solution; unless this is just a generic "is it possible" question.

Comment: @JohnKraft Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @PedroC88: For a _sample_ polymorphic solution, you could have `IMyDummyMethodCaller` interface with a `void MyDummyMethod(<n_params_values>)` method. Then implement a `FooMyDummyMethodCaller : IMyDummyMethodCaller { void MyDummyMethod(<n_params_values>) { MyDummyMethod(<n_params_values>, foo: Guid.Empty);}}` (and an equivalent for `bar`). You'd have some factoryish thing `MyDummyMethodCaller.Get(myType var) { if (var.Prop == 1) return new FooMyDummyMethodCaller(); else return new BarMyDummyMethodCaller(); }`. Then usage code like: `MyDummyMethodCaller.Get(var).MyDummyMethod(n_params_values);`

Comment: @PedroC88: (cont.) but this is really going into the realm of _refactoring_ out the issue altogether which you acknowledge in your question. Seems to me your question was more along the lines of, "Is there a C# _language feature_ that does something _like_ this?"

Comment: If you write an answer with that I'll upvote it (even though I won't mark it as answer), I think with some minor modifications it could be the closer thing I could get for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `params` and naming all parameters might do it:

```
    //void MyDummyMethod(Guid? foo = null, Guid? bar = null, params int[] list)
    //{
    //    //do work            
    //}

    //static void CallingDummyMethod()
    //{
    //    MyClass variable = new MyClass { Prop = 1 }; 
    //    var ints = new int[] {1,2};           
    //    if (variable.Prop == 1)
    //    {
    //        MyDummyMethod(list: ints, foo: Guid.Empty);
    //    }                
    //    else
    //    {
    //        MyDummyMethod(list: ints, bar: Guid.Empty);
    //    }            
    //}
```

**UPDATE** Given comment the fixed params makes the solution easier:

```
   void MyDummyMethod(int one, int two, int three, Guid? foo = null, Guid? bar = null)
    {
        //do work            
    }

    static void CallingDummyMethod()
    {
        MyClass variable = new MyClass { Prop = 1 };            
        if (variable.Prop == 1)
        {
            MyDummyMethod(1,2,3, foo: Guid.Empty);
        }                
        else
        {
            MyDummyMethod(1,2,3, bar: Guid.Empty);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: The n parameters in `MyDummyMethod` are fixed, known, and not optional, I just wrote it like that in the question because they are many, but the use of `params` wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: I think PedroC88 is looking for some way to _avoid_ the `if {callThis} else {callThat}` syntax, or some way to avoid repeating himself.

Comment: @PedroC88: Regarding your edit: Pedro is trying to avoid the duplication of writing "`MyDummyMethod(1, 2, 3`"

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can only be accomplished by overloading the method.

Comment: Yes. That is what it means to overload a method; provide different signatures.

Comment: And how would I distinguish from one another? Note that both foo and bar are of type `Guid?` for an overload to work I would need two different methods with different names.

Comment: @PedroC88: You'd probably have to give them different names like `MyDummyMethodFoo` and `MyDummyMethodBar` (maybe named in some way applicable based on its _actual_ name. Perhaps `FooMyDummyMethod` or `MyDummyMethodWithFoo` are better variants) EDIT: Hrrrm... but really, you got _four_ overloads to deal with (2 optional parameters yields 4 unique combinations) :-/

Comment: Note that in the question I say I know the whole thing could be refactored (actually I did change the method signature), but I was still left wondering if C# had the functionality of allowing you to select specific paramters.

Comment: @PedroC88: I don't think so; at least not this way. Really, the named parameters are a _compile time_ feature. C# will insert the actual values for the optional arguments at compile time, whereas now you want to introduce _runtime_ variations/logic gates to which overload (or which optional parameter values) are used. _Maybe_ you could do some tomfoolery with `dynamic`, or reflection, or _something_, but I would bet money that any of them would be hackish and simply not worthwhile using.

Comment: @PedroC88 If *ALL* of the parameters were defaulted, then you could call the method with named parameters, and only the parameters you wanted; but you'd still have to decide which parameters you wanted to provide before hand.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes, that's what I thought, yet I was actually looking for an answer not involving any of those. I think this is actually not possible as .NET is right now.

Comment: @JohnKraft is not about being defaulted, because they are, the thing is that I want to be able to choose named parameter a or named parameter b based on a condition to assign a given value to one of them.